# Hyperparameter optimization for Neural Network written in keras

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, hyperparameters, talos

Is there a python3 library that optimizes KERAS NN hyperparameters on GPU?

I have tried using sklearn with KerasClassifier wrapper, but it uses cpu.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802939/hyperparameter-tuning-of-tensorflow-model/44803549#44803549) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181511/hyperparameter-tune-for-tensorflow/44182285#44182285) answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can use [Talos](https://github.com/autonomio/talos), which is a hyperparameter optimization solutions specifically for Keras models. It supports both GPU and multi-GPU use.  Full disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the package.